# Using MaybeT with `join`

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Looking at the `MaybeT` transformer:

```
ghci> let x = MaybeT $ Just 1234
ghci> let y = runMaybeT x
ghci> :t y
y :: Num (Maybe a) => Maybe (Maybe a)
```

Now I want to get the inner `Maybe a`, but `join` does not work.

```
ghci> join y

<interactive>:53:1:
    No instance for (Num (Maybe a0)) arising from a use of `it'
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

How can I get at the inner `Maybe a` value?

Comment: `join` from `Control.Monad`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using the `MaybeT` constructor correctly. Look at the type signatures:

```
MaybeT    ::            m   (Maybe a) -> MaybeT m a
                        |   |       |
                      /-+-\ \---+---/
                      |   |     |
Just 1234 :: Num x => Maybe     x
```

Hence:

```
m := Maybe
x := Maybe a
```

Therefore:

```
MaybeT $ Just 1234 :: Num (Maybe a) => MaybeT Maybe a
```

So here `Maybe a` is expected to be an instance of `Num` which is clearly wrong. An option type is not a number. Why does this problem arise?

Consider the numeric literal `1234`. Numeric literals are bounded polymorphic values in Haskell. Hence, they have the type `Num x => x`. In other words `1234` can be of any type depending upon the context as long as that type is an instance of `Num` (e.g. `Int`, `Integer`, `Double`).

In your code, the polymorphic type `x` is instantiated to `Maybe a` which is why Haskell expects `Maybe a` to be an instance of `Num`.

I think what you really want to do is this:

```
MaybeT             ::                     m (Maybe a) -> MaybeT m a

return $ Just 1234 :: (Num a, Monad m) => m (Maybe a)
```

Therefore:

```
MaybeT $ return $ Just 1234 :: (Num a, Monad m) => MaybeT m a
```

Now you can easily extract the inner `Maybe a`:

```
runMaybeT $ MaybeT $ return $ Just 1234 :: (Num a, Monad m) => m (Maybe a)
```

Since the inner `Maybe a` value is wrapped in a monad all you need to do is use `>>=` to extract the `Maybe a`:

```
(runMaybeT $ MaybeT $ return $ Just 1234) >>= \x -> do
    -- do something with x
    -- x :: Maybe a
```

You could also write this using the `do` notation:

```
do
    x <- runMaybeT $ MaybeT $ return $ Just 1234
    -- do something with x
    -- x :: Maybe a
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

The type of `MaybeT` is:

```
MaybeT :: Monad m => m (Maybe a) -> MaybeT m a
```

Accordingly, the type of `MaybeT $ Just 1234` (the expression bound to `x` in your question) is:

```
MaybeT $ Just 1234 :: Num (Maybe a) => MaybeT Maybe a
```

Haskell number literals are overloaded and will interpreted according to what the context demands.  In your case, the "wrapped" monad `m` is `Maybe`, and the compiler tries to interpret the literal `1234` as a `Maybe a`, but there is no `Num` instance.  This explains the type error you encountered.

If you do really want a `MaybeT Maybe a`, your code should read:

```
ghci> let x = MaybeT $ Just $ Just 1234
ghci> :t x
x :: Num a => MaybeT Maybe a
ghci> let y = runMaybeT x
ghci> :t y
y :: Num a => Maybe (Maybe a)
ghci> join y
Just 1234
```

However, it is more likely that you want to use the `MaybeT` transformer to add a *success/failure* or *result/no result* context to an existing (monadic) computation.  A minimal example using the `Identity` monad:

```
ghci> let x = MaybeT $ Identity $ Just 1234
ghci> :t x
x :: Num a => MaybeT Identity a
ghci> let y = runMaybeT x
ghci> :t y
y :: Num a => Identity (Maybe a)
ghci> runIdentity y
Just 1234
```

Comment: ah, so the `a` in `MaybeT m a` is expected to be the wrapped `monad`?

Comment: @KevinMeredith No, the `a` in `MaybeT m a` is not expected to be the wrapped monad. It is expected to be the type of the value inside the wrapped monad. To be clear `MaybeT m a` means a `Maybe a` value wrapped inside a monad `m`. Here the wrapped monad is `Maybe a`, not `a`. The `a` is just the value wrapped in the `Maybe` which is in turn wrapped in the monad `m`.

Comment: Whups, sorry KevinMeredith ; @AaditMShah is right.  Listen to him :)