# Understanding `kind` of MonadTrans

Tags: haskell

Looking at the `kind` of `Monad`:

```
ghci>:k Monad
Monad :: (* -> *) -> Constraint
```

I believe that's because it takes an `a` from `m a`, and returns the `Monad` constraint.

Looking at `MonadTrans`'s *`kind`, I see:

```
ghci>:i MonadTrans
class MonadTrans (t :: (* -> *) -> * -> *) where
  lift :: Monad m => m a -> t m a
        -- Defined in `Control.Monad.Trans.Class'
instance MonadTrans MaybeT
  -- Defined in `Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe'
```

So, the first `(* -> *)` comes from `Monad`'s `kind`, I believe. But what about the `* -> *`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second `* -> *` also comes from `Monad`'s kind! A monad transformer takes a type argument that is a `Monad` (or at least a type that has the kind of a `Monad`) and produces a new type which is a `Monad` (which also has the kind of a `Monad`).

```
 * -> *            -- a Monad
(* -> *) -> * -> * -- Something that takes a Monad and makes a new Monad.
            * -> * -- also a Monad
```

Comment: Thanks!  Could you please check out my related question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/29505152/409976?